# How to get the row item of ListView via a Button?

Tags: xamarin.forms

To get the selected item of a `ListView` it's easily by:

```
myObject myObjectName = e.Item as myObject ;
```

And that's `ItemTappedEventArgs` has `Item` attribute.

But how to get the if I want to position a button inside the cells and I want to get the item of the cell whose button is clicked while `EventArgs` has no `Item` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do that task is putting `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` into your `ListView` and in the code behind:

```
TappedEventArgs tappedEventArgs = e as TappedEventArgs;
myObject myObjectName = tappedEventArgs.Parameter as myObject ;
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this, bind your item list to Itemsource of the listview, if you have a button or image which has a tapped event mapped like below, you can get the selected item from the list. the code is casting to Image as the event is mapped to Tap gesture of an Image.

Image inside listview will be,

```
<Image  Source="app_dots" Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                                            Tapped="more_Tapped"
                                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
```

and the code for Tap event,

```
async void more_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationModel applicationModel = ((ApplicationModel)((Image)sender).BindingContext);
        if (applicationModel != null)
        {
            //do your logic;
        }
    }
```